# d3 force nodes toggle

Tags: d3.js, toggle, force-layout

I'm trying to write a click, toggle function on the nodes in a d3 force layout and haven't been anything that helps me figure out how to get this working. The idea is that when you click on a node, an svg appears from the left side of the screen, and when you click again, it disappears. Here is the code that I'm trying on it without any luck:

```js
    var tooltip = svg.append("rect")
            .attr("x", -300)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", 300)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("color", "black")
            .attr("opacity", 0.8);
    
    var toggleWindow = (function () {
        var currentStatus = -300;
        
        return function () {
            currentStatus = currentStatus === -300 ? 0 : -300;
            d3.select(tooltip).attr("x", currentStatus);
        };
    })();
    
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(json.nodes)
            .enter().append("g")
            .on("mouseover", mouseover)
            .on("mouseout", mouseout)
            .on("click", toggleWindow)
            .call(force.drag);
```

And here's a link to the full code: http://plnkr.co/edit/nwmUN4RzAwam9dE5bCEj?p=preview

Comment: currently on the left side you have a black rectangle...are you saying that it should slide in on first click then slide out on second click on the same node? what will happen if some one click on node1 then click node2..?

Comment: Yes it should slide out to the right on the first click and slide in when you click on the node. That happens for every node you click on. The difference though is that for each click, it populates the rectangle with text from the json that corresponds to each specific node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it. First make a tooltip group.

```
  var tooltip = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(-300,0)");
  //add rectangle to the group
  tooltip.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("color", "black")
    .attr("opacity", 0.8);
```

On node click

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)
    .on("click", function(d) {
      if (tooltip.data && d.name == tooltip.data.name) {
        //if clicked on the same node again close
        tooltip.classed("open", false);
        tooltip
          .transition()
          .attr("transform", "translate(-300,0)")//slide via translate
          .duration(1000);
        tooltip.data = undefined;//set the data to be undefined since the tooltip is closed
        return;
      }
      tooltip.data = d;//set the data to the opened node
      tooltip.classed("open", true);//set the class as open since the tooltip is opened
      tooltip
        .transition()
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
        .duration(1000);
      d3.selectAll(".text-tip").remove();  //remove old text
      tooltip.append("text")//set the value to the text
      .attr("transform", "translate(10,100)")
      .attr("class","text-tip").text(d.name);

    })
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/M1lRqYRwzv8mCFAIdc18?p=preview).

Comment: This is great, thanks so much! Have you ever worked with text wrapping in SVG? I've heard that d3plus gives you this option, but I've been having  trouble integrating it with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can add :

Need to define :

```
var COLLAPSE_LEVEL = 1
```

And use the below code :

```
 function toggleAll(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
                if (d.level < COLLAPSE_LEVEL) {
                    return;
                }
                toggle(d);
            }
        }

 function toggle(d) {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children= null;
        } else {
            d.children= d._children;
            d._children = null;
        }
    }
```